# Use node `fs` module on webpack compile

Tags: node.js, webpack, fs

A bit about what I'm trying to achieve.
I'm building [dev library](https://github.com/asvae/vue-component-tree) that shows the list of files. And I want to set file color depending on when file was changed.
So, as a result of generation, I want an array like this:

```js
[
  {
    lastChange: '2009-06-29T11:11:55Z',
    fileContents: {name: 'VmSome'},
  },
// ...
]
```

This is meant to work in browser environment. Meaning all file related information should be included into bundle.

#### Current progress

At the moment I'm not quite sure whether that's even possible.

I'm getting a list of files via webpack [require.context](https://webpack.github.io/docs/context.html):

`require.context('./tree', true, /.js$/)`

This gives me access to file content and path. But not to anything else.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: It is certainly possible... But you need to help us by providing more of your context and your code.

Comment: @Salketer added some info. Also I'm looking for realistic solution. Writing my own webpack won't do.

Answer (score 0):

I would first try modifying webpack-file-list-plugin. As of now, it creates a JSON that gives all files packed, their name and some more info... You could definitely add your code to fetch more information to the JSON.

https://github.com/object88/webpack-file-list-plugin/blob/master/src/index.js

Comment: As far as my understanding goes, that would require user of my library to install additional plugin just to get that tiny feature.

Comment: I guess so. I might be wrong tough. But I doubt you'd get the information another way than from webpack. I've tried looking at your github but couldn't get enough info on how exactly your tool works so it is hard to tell to what it has access.

Comment: My tool uses exactly one line of code to access files: `require.context('./tree', true, /.js$/)`. Then it just operates on webpack `requireContext`. Code [here](https://github.com/asvae/vue-component-tree/blob/master/src/classes/Main/DemoPage.js).